# Comparison element group in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i am trying to split a list into n/2 groups (n = length of list) and to compare occurrences of each group.

When i try to write my code as:

`_3_hop_middle_cells = ['E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'C']`

`_3_hop_middle_cells = np.array(_3_hop_middle_cells)`

`_3_hop_middle_cells = list(np.split(_3_hop_middle_cells, len(_3_hop_middle_cells)/2))`

and the output of **_3_hop_middle_cells** is:

```
 array(['E', 'D'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['D', 'C'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['C', 'D'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['D', 'E'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['D', 'C'], dtype='<U1')]
```

After that, when I try to count zeroth element with

`_3_hop_middle_cells.count(_3_hop_middle_cells[0])`

it throws an error as

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Would you please help me for me to handle my problem?

*PS: I am fairly new at stackoverflow, for that, I am very sorry if my question looks silly..*

Comment: I am expecting 1 (since zeroth element of array (i.e., ['E','D']) occurred once). If code wouldn't give me problem, i was going to implement it to bigger array, that has some repeating element groups, and take maximum occurred among them.

Comment: Please edit your post to concretely describe what you're trying to generate.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that error, use `np.array_equal`. Since your `_3_hop_middle_cells` is a list of numpy arrays, the easiest way to count the number of occurences is the following list comprehension:

```
sum([1 for item in _3_hop_middle_cells if np.array_equal(item, _3_hop_middle_cells[0])])
```

Or, written out as a for-loop:

```
count = 0
for item in _3_hop_middle_cells:
    if np.array_equal(item, _3_hop_middle_cells[0]):
        count += 1
```